# RatingBar выделяется задний план

Tags: android, xml

Пробую использовать `RatingBar` но чет не понятно как убрать выделение когда зажимаешь `RatingBar` и влево или вправо выставляешь количество звезд, к примеру как на рисунке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/startBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:stepSize="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

Подскажите какой метод отвечает за это, спасибо.

Comment: Попробуй сделать кастомный стиль:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/ratingbar.php

Comment: @ViR спасибо, получилось!